# sync.Cond not woking properly with multiple goroutines

Tags: multithreading, go, concurrency, synchronization, goroutine

I am trying to print in multiple go routines only when `sync.Cond` does Broadcasts but the go routines are deadlocking. Is there any way the below code can be improved and are there any ways to identify why this code is deadlocking?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type Button struct {
    Clicked *sync.Cond
}

func subscribe(cond *sync.Cond, btnMessage string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    cond.L.Lock()
    defer cond.L.Unlock()

    cond.Wait()
    fmt.Println(btnMessage)
}

func test6() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    button := Button{
        Clicked: sync.NewCond(&sync.Mutex{}),
    }

    wg.Add(3)
    go subscribe(button.Clicked, "Button 1", &wg)
    go subscribe(button.Clicked, "Button 2", &wg)
    go subscribe(button.Clicked, "Button 3", &wg)

    // Start the goroutines before broadcasting
    button.Clicked.Broadcast()

    wg.Wait()
}

func main() {
    test6()
}
```

I got this below deadlock error

```
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [semacquire]:
sync.runtime_Semacquire(0x466df7?)
    /nix/store/akhjsmrrsakcnj8x3xgygvizhccbyn0v-go-1.19.3/share/go/src/runtime/sema.go:62 +0x25
sync.(*WaitGroup).Wait(0x405399?)
    /nix/store/akhjsmrrsakcnj8x3xgygvizhccbyn0v-go-1.19.3/share/go/src/sync/waitgroup.go:139 +0x52
main.test6()
    /home/runner/concurrency-in-go/main.go:36 +0x199
main.main()
    /home/runner/concurrency-in-go/main.go:40 +0x17

goroutine 6 [sync.Cond.Wait]:
sync.runtime_notifyListWait(0xc000108050, 0x1)
    /nix/store/akhjsmrrsakcnj8x3xgygvizhccbyn0v-go-1.19.3/share/go/src/runtime/sema.go:517 +0x14c
sync.(*Cond).Wait(0x0?)
    /nix/store/akhjsmrrsakcnj8x3xgygvizhccbyn0v-go-1.19.3/share/go/src/sync/cond.go:70 +0x8c
main.subscribe(0xc000108040, {0x49962f, 0x8}, 0x0?)
    /home/runner/concurrency-in-go/main.go:17 +0xbb
created by main.test6
    /home/runner/concurrency-in-go/main.go:29 +0xdb

goroutine 7 [sync.Cond.Wait]:
sync.runtime_notifyListWait(0xc000108050, 0x2)
    /nix/store/akhjsmrrsakcnj8x3xgygvizhccbyn0v-go-1.19.3/share/go/src/runtime/sema.go:517 +0x14c
sync.(*Cond).Wait(0x0?)
    /nix/store/akhjsmrrsakcnj8x3xgygvizhccbyn0v-go-1.19.3/share/go/src/sync/cond.go:70 +0x8c
main.subscribe(0xc000108040, {0x499637, 0x8}, 0x0?)
    /home/runner/concurrency-in-go/main.go:17 +0xbb
created by main.test6
    /home/runner/concurrency-in-go/main.go:30 +0x12f

goroutine 8 [sync.Cond.Wait]:
sync.runtime_notifyListWait(0xc000108050, 0x0)
    /nix/store/akhjsmrrsakcnj8x3xgygvizhccbyn0v-go-1.19.3/share/go/src/runtime/sema.go:517 +0x14c
sync.(*Cond).Wait(0x0?)
    /nix/store/akhjsmrrsakcnj8x3xgygvizhccbyn0v-go-1.19.3/share/go/src/sync/cond.go:70 +0x8c
main.subscribe(0xc000108040, {0x49963f, 0x8}, 0x0?)
    /home/runner/concurrency-in-go/main.go:17 +0xbb
created by main.test6
    /home/runner/concurrency-in-go/main.go:31 +0x185
exit status 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're broadcasting before your goroutines even initialize. So you end up Broadcasting and then waiting again. If you insert a sleep in your main thread you can see it starts to work.

[Playground with it working](https://go.dev/play/p/ef7mLdDfh1l)

You should only wait in your goroutine when certain criteria are met. Depending on your actual use case, you might consider a different synchronization primitive.

Comment: To demonstrate this, if we wait for goroutines to start, and then broadcast, it'll work. https://go.dev/play/p/VP9f_LvIBXB

Comment: Thanks for explaining, I understood why it's not working, Appreciate your effort